# Is such a 2 photons interaction possible, and what would be its result?

Tags: photons, collision, interference

Let's consider 2 photons of the same frequency .

Is it possible to consider the following situation (of very low probability and certainly nearly impossible to produce, consider this as a theoretical experiment if you prefer):
these 2 photons are in the exact same position, following the same strait line at speed c, and have opposite phases.

Is it valid to consider the frequency and the phase of a single photon?

Will there be any kind of interaction between these 2 photons?

What will the result look like in term of wave signal?

Will this be looking like an electro-magnetic signal of amplitude 0, with an energy of 2h?

Comment: What does "2 photons are in the exact same position" and "have opposite phases" mean? How do you localize a relativistic particle like the photon, and what do you mean by the phase of a single photon?

Comment: From my point of vue, a photon, as a quantum of electromagnetic field, is characterized by a frequency, a speed a direction and a phase. Is this wrong?

Comment: I don't see any easy way to bring 2 photons in the "exact same position". Let's consider this question as a thought experiment or a very low probability event.

Comment: The point is *not* that it is difficult to get two photons "into the same position". The point is that photons don't *have* a definite position at all, so it is unclear *even in principle* what it means for them to be at the "exact same position".

Comment: Is there an exclusion principle for photons?

Comment: You are right, there is a phenomenon called photon bunching: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect

Comment: To the question "Will there be any kind of interaction between 2 photons": There exists an interaction, look at "photon-photon-scattering" (see for example here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.6126.pdf)

Comment: @Alpha001: great analysis of the transparency of the CMRB which let us see photons behind Jupiter.